# Como configurar o passthrough do Slim 3?

Tags: api, jwt, slimframework

Estou tentando montar uma API simples para estudo com Slim Framework e JWTAuthentication. No caso meu path /auth retorna um JSON contendo o token JWT que será utilizado para acessar os outros paths. Porém ao tentar acessar o /auth o JWTAuthentication retorna um STATUS code 401, mesmo eu configurando o passthrough ao recurso /auth.

Agora se eu colocar "ignore" ao invés de "passthrough" ele funciona certinho.

Arquivo .htaccess

```html
RewriteEngine On
 
RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Meu index.php

```html
<?php

require "vendor/autoload.php";

use Firebase\JWT\JWT;

$container['secret'] = "secretloko";

$app = new \Slim\App($container);

$app->add(new \Tuupola\Middleware\HttpBasicAuthentication([

 //Lista de usuários
 "users" => [
  "root" => "toor"
 ],

 "paths" => ["/auth"]

]));

$app->add(new \Tuupola\Middleware\JWTAuthentication([
    "path" => "/",
    "passthrough" => ["/auth"],
    "secret" => $container['secret'],
    "error" => function ($options) use ($app) {
     print_r($options);
 }

]));

$app->get("/auth", function ($request, $response, $args) use ($app){

 $key = $this->get('secret');

 $payload = array(
  "iss" => "root",
  "adm" => "true"
  );

  $jwt = JWT::encode($payload, $key);

 return $response->withJson(["token" => $jwt], 200)->withHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
});

$app->run();

?>
```

Resultado ao tentar acessa http://localhost/auth

```html
Slim\Http\Response Object
(
    [status:protected] => 401
    [reasonPhrase:protected] => 
    [protocolVersion:protected] => 1.1
    [headers:protected] => Slim\Http\Headers Object
        (
            [data:protected] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [body:protected] => Slim\Http\Body Object
        (
            [stream:protected] => Resource id #72
            [meta:protected] => 
            [readable:protected] => 
            [writable:protected] => 
            [seekable:protected] => 
            [size:protected] => 
            [isPipe:protected] => 
        )

)
```